# connect Rest API in R (plumber) with Kafka

Tags: r, apache-kafka, plumber

I'm looking for information on the possibility of connecting to `Kafka` using the `Rest API` written in `R` (based on the `plumber` library). Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything useful. Does anyone have knowledge about this? Does this mean that it is currently impossible?

I'm mainly interested in the process of connecting to `Kafka` in listening mode, but I couldn't even find information on how to send a message to the `Kafka` queue.

Could anyone share their knowledge or resources on this topic? Alternatively, please inform me that such functionality does not currently exist.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has no HTTP protocol without extra, external tools like Confluent REST Proxy, or ksqlDB pull queries.

Perhaps you should be using something else like [`rkafka`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rkafka/versions/1.4) (no experience, was first search result)